# При нажатии на кнопку отобразить на Textview случайные числа с задержками

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Я хочу сделать приложение с задержкой, т.е. отображается первое, затем через секунду второе и снова через секунду третье число. При нажатии на кнопку я хочу отобразить случайные числа с задержкой на Textview. Но на Textview ничего не отображается. Кажется в цикле for есть ошибка. Помогите мне найти ошибку. Заранее спасибо.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Button mStartButton, mCancelButton;
    private TextView mCounterTextView;

    private Timer mTimer;
    private MyTimerTask mMyTimerTask;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
        mCancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel);
        mCounterTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCounter);

        mStartButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if (mTimer != null) {
                    mTimer.cancel();
                }

                mTimer = new Timer();
                mMyTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();

                if (mStartButton.isClickable() ){

                            mTimer.schedule(mMyTimerTask, 0, 1000);

                }
            }
        });

        mCancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mTimer != null) {
                    mTimer.cancel();
                    mTimer = null;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {


            @Override
            public void run () {
                final Random random = new Random();
                final String number = String.valueOf(random.nextInt());


                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        for (int i=1; i<=3; i++) {
                            mCounterTextView.setText(number);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }


    }
}
```

Comment: Дебаггер в помощь. В цикле нет необходимости, а так код рабочий должен быть.

Answer (score 1):

Можно же проще код написать, без костылей, подводных камней и вложенных классов :)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final long DELAY = 1000; // задержка 1 секунда
    private static final int MAX_GENERATE_NUMBER_COUNT = 3;

    private TextView mCounterTextView;
    private final Random mRandom = new Random();
    private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mGenerateNumberCount < MAX_GENERATE_NUMBER_COUNT) {
                String numberString = String.valueOf(mRandom.nextInt());
                mCounterTextView.setText(numberString);
                generateNumberPostDelay();
                mGenerateNumberCount++;
            }
        }
    };
    private int mGenerateNumberCount = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mCounterTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCounter);

        findViewById(R.id.buttonStart).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mGenerateNumberCount = 0;
                generateNumberPostDelay();
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCounterTextView.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
            }
        });
    }

    private void generateNumberPostDelay() {
        mCounterTextView.postDelayed(mRunnable, DELAY);
    }
}
```

А если Вам надо, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку `start` самое первое число отобразилось без задержки, то в `Listener`-е на этой кнопке добавьте одну строчку:

```
findViewById(R.id.buttonStart).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        mGenerateNumberCount = 0;
        mRunnable.run(); // вот эту строчку
        generateNumberPostDelay();
    }
});
```

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку выдает: "Unfortunately, application has stopped."

Comment: @Aim023 , я ошибся, когда int передавал в метод setText, не та сигнатура вызывалась, обновил код, пробуйте снова :)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте рандом и таймер , по типу:

```
Число = рандом число ;

Таймер + число каждую секунду ;

Если таймер = 10 {
    Число = рандом число ;
    Таймер = 0;
}
```